# How can I use different "where" clauses depending on a parameter?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Take this sample code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetCars] 
    @carModelID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,   
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    IF @carModelID IS NULL
    BEGIN
        SELECT *
        FROM dbo.Cars
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SELECT *
        FROM dbo.Cars
        WHERE ModelID = @carModelID 
          AND Color = 'red'
    END
END
GO
```

Can I somehow avoid typing the select code twice and avoid the BEGIN ELSE? Something like this...

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetCars] 
    @carModelID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,   
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT *
    FROM dbo.Cars
    WHERE
        (Here I need to filter a filter, where it will return all rows, 
         if @carModelID is NULL - and if @carModelID is not null, it must 
         return all rows where cars are red and carModelID equals @carModelID)
END
GO
```

Comment: Create a *view* instead. Use different queries instead of one stored procedure that tries to act as different queries. You gain nothing in terms of performance, security or maintainability by having a `catch-all` stored procedure

Comment: BTW using `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER` as a key is a *very* bad idea, unless a sequential GUID algorithm is used. The generated values will end up adding records at any point in the table resulting in constant table and index fragmentation

Answer (score 0):

you can use this.

```
SELECT *
        FROM dbo.Cars
        WHERE @carModelID IS NULL 
        OR ( ModelID = @carModelID AND
                      Color = 'red')
```

Comment: [Catch-all queries](https://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2018/03/13/revisiting-catch-all-queries/) cause a *lot* of performance problems. The server will cache the execution plan created for the *first* query execution, which is most likely inappropriate for different values. In this particular case, the execution plan for `NULL` could use a table scan, something inappropriate if a specific ID is provided.

Comment: totally agree with @PanagiotisKanavos. It would be better to write separate queries for each parameter or use technique mentioned by Gail in the following article. https://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2018/03/13/revisiting-catch-all-queries/

Comment: For complex queries can cause performance problems. but this kind of simple parameter checks I did not encounter any problem by now. And also this not makes my answer wrong because the need is merge two select to one.

Comment: @SerkanArslan this is actually the *worst* case - full table scans vs index seeks depending on the first ID value. *Complex* queries may not suffer so much, but in *this* case using the wrong operation can have a huge impact. Instead of searching for a single record by PK in 10K rows, you can end up scanning all 10K rows. Or instead of just returning all rows without filtering, end up reading the index only to go back to the table to get the rows

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos But the question is not about the performance. it may not be the best answer, but it is not wrong.